# What's the basic steps to show a set is denumerable?

Tags: number-theory

For example, $\mathbb{N}$ is denumerable.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}$ are all denumerable since they are countably infinite. Its a definition that we don't prove. You might prove the case $\mathbb{Q}$ using Cantor's diagonal trick.

Comment: Write down the definition of *denumerable* and notice that nothing needs to be shown for $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set $A$ is denumerable iff there exists (at least) one injective function $f:A\to\Bbb N$ and one injective function $g:\Bbb N\to A$. For $A=\Bbb N$ the identity is such a function (so is "add one" or "multiply by two", so there are many). For any other set you have to look for such functions.